# INSERT data from another table to another table with input OLEDB visual studio

Tags: insert-into, oledbcommand

I want to get the value of Table1(vID) to auto transfer in table VOTED(vID) while the query has an select and insert this is what i am trying but i cant get it fix pls help.

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Try
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO VOTED(vID) " & _
                                 " VALUES (" & _
                                 "SELECT(vID) FROM Table1 " & _
                                 " WHERE (" & position & ")"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cnn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully")
            refreshdata()
    Catch ex As OleDbException When ex.ErrorCode = -2147467259
        MsgBox("FAILED")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error? Also capture the CommandText as a variable and display its value in the question so we can see any syntax errors etc

Comment: position is a string in the INSERT sql. i want to do is. how can i select or call the vID from TABLE1 and auto input it in TABLE2 after logging in? and when clicking the submit button it would send a value to position while auto inserting the vID.

Comment: by the way this is the error.
Syntax error. in query expression 'SELECT(vID) FROM Table1  WHERE (SELECT vID from Table1,1)'.

Comment: 0
down vote
So 'SELECT(vID) FROM Table1 WHERE (SELECT vID from Table1,1)'. is not a valid SQL Statement. That is why it says "Syntax error." Perhaps send me a tsql DDL script for the table designs and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

So 'SELECT(vID) FROM Table1 WHERE (SELECT vID from Table1,1)'. is not a valid SQL Statement. That is why it says "Syntax error."
Perhaps send me a tsql DDL script for the table designs and what you are trying to accomplish.